# Incorrect Result while using the city,countryCode format

Tags: java, openweathermap

I'm tryig to get the weather based on the city and country code format using the below URL.
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Hyderabad,IN&appid=_myAppId

This is giving me the climate in Hyderabad in India

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Hyderabad,PK&appid=_myAppId

This gives me the Hyderabad Climate in Pakistan. Now here is the issue

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Hyderabad,AU&appid=_myAppId

When I run this URL I get the result of the Hyderabad in India, but technically speaking this should throw an exception since there is no city in Australia named Hyderabad.

Please let me know how can I come across this bug. There are a lot of validations at my ed based on the result that this returns.

Thanks

Comment: *Please let me know how can I come across this bug.* you already came across this bug?

Comment: You're basing validations at your "ed" (whatever that is), based on information returned to you by a *weather service*? Are you for real?

Comment: This is something you'll have to take up with the API developer.